# Detect simultaneous left and right clicks in tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter

Tried doing some searches but was not able to get the answer however if this has been asked before kindly direct me to that post.

I have a button in python and would want to bind that button to a leftClick, rightClick and bothClick functions. bothClick function being clicking and/or releasing both right and left mouse button on the button GUI at the same time.

How can I do the bothClick?

Also bind it so that it does not trigger leftClick and/or rightClick when bothClick is triggered.

NOTE: this is similar to doing a left click, right click and clicking both mouse buttons in minesweeper.

Comment: In `leftClick` wait a moment and check whether right mouse was click then do job for left click or for both click. In `rightClick` wait a moment and check whether left mouse was click then do job for right click or do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only modification of [tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2348704/tao) example.

It prints  `left pressed`, `right pressed` and `both pressed`
but only when mouse buttons are released - sometimes it is enough.

```
import Tkinter
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.left_mouse_pressed = False
        self.right_mouse_pressed = False

        f = Tkinter.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="cyan")
        f.pack()

        f.bind("<Button-1>", self.onAnyofTwoPressed)
        f.bind("<Button-3>", self.onAnyofTwoPressed)

        f.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.resetPressedState)
        f.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", self.resetPressedState)

    def onAnyofTwoPressed(self, event):
        if self.left_mouse_pressed and self.left_mouse_pressed <= time.time():
            self.left_mouse_pressed = False

        if self.right_mouse_pressed and self.right_mouse_pressed <= time.time():
            self.right_mouse_pressed = False

        if event.num==1:
            self.left_mouse_pressed = time.time() + 500
        if event.num==3:
            self.right_mouse_pressed = time.time() + 500


    def resetPressedState(self, event):
        if self.left_mouse_pressed and self.right_mouse_pressed:
            print 'both pressed'
        elif self.left_mouse_pressed:
            print 'left pressed'
        elif self.right_mouse_pressed:
            print 'rigth pressed'

        self.left_mouse_pressed = False
        self.right_mouse_pressed = False

root=Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** my version with `after()` - it prints when mouse buttons are pressed

300 in `after()` is 'time for reaction'.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

left_pressed = False
rigth_pressed = False

def on_left_click(event):
    global left_pressed, rigth_pressed

    if rigth_pressed:
        rigth_pressed = False
    else:        
        left_pressed = True

    root.after(300, on_left_later)

def on_left_later():        
    global left_pressed

    if left_pressed:
        left_pressed = False
        print "left pressed"
    else:
        print "both pressed"

def on_right_click(event):
    global left_pressed, rigth_pressed

    if left_pressed:
        left_pressed = False
    else:
        rigth_pressed = True

    root.after(300, on_right_later)

def on_right_later():
    global rigth_pressed

    if rigth_pressed:
        rigth_pressed = False
        print "rigth pressed"
#    else:
#        print "(right_do_nothing)"

button = tk.Button(root, text="Clik me! - left, right, both")
button.pack()
button.bind('<Button-1>',on_left_click)
button.bind('<Button-3>',on_right_click)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Gotta bump myself in the head for not thinking about using a flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this is as follows.

Use two variables `left_mouse_pressed` and `right_mouse_pressed`.
When both are simultaneously `True`, both mouse keys pressed.

Reset their state to `False` on mouse release.

```
import Tkinter

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.left_mouse_pressed = False
        self.right_mouse_pressed = False

        f = Tkinter.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="cyan")
        f.pack()

        f.bind("<Button-1>", self.onAnyofTwoPressed)
        f.bind("<Button-3>", self.onAnyofTwoPressed)

        f.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.resetPressedState)
        f.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", self.resetPressedState)

    def onAnyofTwoPressed(self, event):
        if event.num==1:
            self.left_mouse_pressed = True
        if event.num==3:
            self.right_mouse_pressed = True
        if (self.left_mouse_pressed and self.right_mouse_pressed):
            print 'yay both pressed'



    def resetPressedState(self, event):
            self.left_mouse_pressed = False
            self.right_mouse_pressed = False

root=Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How to get `left pressed`, `right pressed` and `both pressed` with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
self.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e:self.func())
```