# Detect simultaneous left and right clicks using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

I want to write a simple program to detect simultaneous left and right mouse clicks using tkinter. I referred to the question [Detect simultaneous left and right clicks in tkinter gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469090/detect-simultaneous-left-and-right-clicks-in-tkinter-gui) and made some changes, but came across some problems. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def call_back_left(event, v, h):
    global left, right
    if right:
        right = False
    else:
        left = True
    root.after(1000, left_judge_right(v, h))

def left_judge_right(v, h):
    global left, right
    if left:
        print(f'Button on row{v}, column{h}\t\tleft click')
        left = False
    else:
        print(f'Button on row{v}, column{h}\t\tboth clicks')

def call_back_right(event, v, h):
    global left, right
    if left:
        left = False
    else:
        right = True
    root.after(1000, right_judge_left, v, h)

def right_judge_left(v, h):
    global left, right
    if right:
        print(f'Button on row{v}, column{h}\t\tright click')
        right = False
    else:
        pass

left = False
right = False
root = Tk()
vertical, horizontal = 4, 4
map_area = Frame(root, pady=10)
map_area.pack(side=TOP)

for v in range(vertical):
    for h in range(horizontal):
        button = Button(map_area, text=' ', width=5, height=2)
        button.grid(row=v, column=h)
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, i=v, j=h: call_back_left(event, i, j))
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, i=v, j=h: call_back_right(event, i, j))

root.mainloop()
```

The detection for both clicks sometimes worked but sometimes didn't, so I made the first parameter to the `root.after()` function to be 1000 microseconds (as shown in the codes).

As I understand, if I run the code above and do left click firstly then right click within 1 second, the function running sequence should be:

call_back_left --> call_back_right --> wait about 1 sec --> left_judge_right --> right_judge_left

And the print outcome should be:

"Button on rowX, columnY both clicks"

However, the result is:

"Button on rowX, columnY left click"

"Button on rowX, columnY right click"

It seemed like the function running sequence is:

call_back_left --> left_judge_right --> wait about 1 sec --> call_back_right --> right_judge_left

Then I tried doing right click firstly and then left click within 1 sec, and it worked fine without any problems.

Please tell me why this problem occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you do this so complicated? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Atlas435 I just want to write a program with horizontal x vertical buttons, and each button can respond to three operations: left click, right click, and left and right clicks. It is kind of similar to the game Minesweeper.

Comment: The 1000 that you have in the after statement is 1000 milliseconds (= 1 second) not 1000 microseconds.

Comment: Personally I'd look at recording the time of each button press and if the buttons have been pressed within X milliseconds of each other, trigger the "both buttons" event

Comment: @scotty3785Thanks for correcting me. I confused milliseconds with microseconds, but the code is correct, and 1 sec is exactly what I want.

Comment: @scotty3785 I found another solution to this, which is to bind the buttons with two other events: left released and right released.